# Question about sums of normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ such that $X_1 \sim N(1,1)$ and $X_2 \sim N(2,2)$, and I'm trying to find a constant $a$ such that $a(X_1 - X_2 + 1)^2$ has a chi-squared distribution.

I'm pretty sure that the sum of $y=(X_i + X_j)^2$ generally is a chi-squared distribution. But the process is eluding me, so could use some help.

Comment: A linear combination of normal variables (and constants) is normal

Comment: Do you want to have a centered chi-squared?

Comment: @MPW Does that mean I have to find the joint PDF of $X_1 - X_2$?

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, looking for centered chi-squared.

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent? Add information about that to your question.

Comment: @drhab Yeah, they're independent r.v.s. Sorry about that, edited original post to include that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle Y=X_1-X_2+1\sim N(0,3)$ (assuming independence). Therefore $\displaystyle \sqrt{c} Y\sim N(0,1)$ if we choose $\displaystyle c=\frac{1}{3}$, that is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3} (X_1-X_2+1)^2 \sim \chi_{(1)}^2$.

Comment: Are you using the fact that if $Z \sim N(0,1)$, then $Z^2 \sim \chi_{(1)}^2 $?

Comment: This is what I used...